# binary search tree "remove" function

Tags: c++, c, binary-search-tree

Trying to write a remove function for a binary search tree. I know there are three possible cases to consider but I'm not really sure where to start.

My troubles atm mostly stem from the fact that once I locate the node that needs to be removed, I need to set it's PARENT node to node after the node that needs to be removed. Should I use a cursor to hold on to the parent node or something?

I have a struct for the node:

```
struct bt_node {
  int data;
  bt_node* left;
  bt_node* right;
};
```

And the definition for the remove function is set up as such:

```
void remove(bt_node** top_ref, int data);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try holding a cursor to the parent? was there a problem with that approach? It seems like you know where to start, and just haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to extend the search code to keep track of the "last" parent in a second reference as you travel down the tree.  This "extended" search then returns back the node and the node's parent.

Then you use that search function by your delete function, so you don't have to do any fancy stuff in your delete logic.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to do it would be using recursion. You ask your delete function to return a reference to the current node back to the calling function. That way you can easily modify the parent nodes.
Here is some recursive code for your reference:

**Structure Declaration:**

```
 typedef struct node {
    int info;
    struct node* lchild;
    struct node* rchild;
}NODE;
```

**Code for deletion :**

```
NODE* deleteElem(NODE* root, int elem) {
    NODE* save;
    if(root == NULL) {
        printf("Element not in the tree !\n");
        return;
    }
    if(root->info == elem) {
        if(root->rchild == NULL && root->lchild == NULL) {                  // no child
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if(root->rchild == NULL || root->lchild == NULL) {             // one child
            if(root->rchild == NULL) {
                save = root->lchild;
                free(root);
                return save;
            }
            else {
                save = root->rchild;
                free(root);
                return save;
            }
        }
        else {                                                             // two children
            save = findPred(root->lchild);
            root->info = save->info;
            root->lchild = deleteElem(root->lchild, root->info);
            return root;
        }
    }
    else if(root->info < elem) {
        root->rchild = deleteElem(root->rchild, elem);
    }
    else if(root->info > elem) {
        root->lchild = deleteElem(root->lchild, elem);
    }
    return root;
}
NODE* findPred(NODE* root) {
    static NODE* pred;
    if(root == NULL) {
        return pred;
    }
    else {
        pred = root;
        return findPred(root->rchild);
    }
}
```

**P.S** : Sorry, I just noticed the prototype declaration for your function. I hope that changing this code to match your prototype declaration shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
void delete_tree(struct tree **ptr,int item) 
{ 
      struct tree *move,*back,*temp; 

      if(*ptr==NULL) 
      { 
               printf("nEmpty tree..............n"); 
               return; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
               move=*ptr; 
               back=move;

               while(move->info!=item) 
               { 
                         back=move;

                         if(item<move->info) 
                         {
                                   move=move->left; 
                         } 
                         else 
                         { 
                                  move=move->right; 
                         } 
               }

               if(move->left!=NULL&&move->right!=NULL) 
               {

                         temp=move->right;

                         while(temp->left!=NULL) 
                         { 
                                  back=temp; 
                                  temp=temp->left; 
                         }

                         move->info=temp->info; 
                         move=temp; 
               }

               if(move->left==NULL&&move->right==NULL) 
               { 
                         if(back->right==move) 
                         { 
                                  back->right=NULL; 
                         } 
                         else 
                         { 
                                  back->left=NULL; 
                         }

                         free(move); 
                         return; 
               }

               if(move->left==NULL && move->right!=NULL) 
               { 
                         if(back->left==move) 
                         { 
                                  back->left=move->right; 
                         } 
                         else 
                         { 
                                  back->right=move->right; 
                         }

                         free(move); 
                         return; 
               }

               if(move->left!=NULL && move->right==NULL) 
               {
                          if(back->left==move) 
                         { 
                                  back->left=move->left; 
                         } 
                         else 
                         { 
                                  back->right=move->left; 
                         }

                         free(move); 
                         return;
```